# Gradle build script - attach local Javadoc to dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

In my `build.gradle` file I configured my .jar dependencies like that:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Now I need to attach a Javadoc directory, which is `libs/doc`, for the `fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` dependencies. How can I do that?

Comment: I guess you need javadoc for IDE? because there normally javadoc dependency is not usefull for anything else..

  could you check flatDir repo (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html) and have javadoc in same directory as your dependencies?